# How to run two functions at the same time in matlab and wait till any one is completed?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, function, output, execution

I am having two functions and both need to run simultaneously. However, its just speed test so whenever any one of them throws an output and completes their part of execution, the execution of '.m' should stop.

Comment: It is an speed test? You know you can time functions so you know exactly how much time they take?

Answer (score 0):

How about running two functions using parfor? Check the below code:

```
funcs = {@exp,@sin} ;
args = {2,pi/4} ;
sols = cell(1,2) ;
parfor n = 1:2
    sols{n}=funcs{n}(args{n});
end
M = sols{1} ; N = sols{2} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
p = gcp();
funcs = {@exp,@sin};
for i=1:numel(funcs)
    f(i) = parfeval(p,funcs{i},1,10);
end

while true
  [idx,value] = fetchNext(f);
  fprintf('Fn indx: %d, Result: %d', idx, value)
  break;
end
```